# Ember.js : how to bind a model attribute on a custom component

Tags: data-binding, ember.js, datepicker

I would like to integrate a date picker in a form. So I created a custom DateTimePickerView like this :

```
App.DateTimePickerView = Em.View.extend
  templateName: 'datetimepicker'
  didInsertElement: ->
    self = this
    onChangeDate = (ev) ->
      self.set "value", moment.utc(ev.date).format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
    @$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(language: 'fr', format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii').on "changeDate", onChangeDate
```

Here is the template :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="datetimepicker" >
  <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" readonly>
</script>
```

In my form I want to bind this component to an attribute of my model (I am using the RestAdapter) :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="post/_edit">
  <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='title'}}</p>
  <p>{{view App.DateTimePickerView valueBinding='date'}}</p>
</script>
```

Everything works fine in apparence : the DateTimePicker is well displayed and the value is set inside the input.
But there is a problem in the effective binding : when I send the form, the post param "date" (corresponding to the attribute) is null.

When I look inside the generated html code I can see the following :

```
<p>
  <input id="ember393" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text" value="Event 1">
</p>
<div id="ember403" class="ember-view">
  <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" readonly="">
</div>
```

I am not an expert in the global ember structure, but I guess that the id element is important for the binding. In that case, for my component, the ember id is put to the container of my component and not to the input containing the value. So I guess the problem is here.

So what could be the correct way to make it work ?

I just created a working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DCrHG/148/) ; we can see that the modifications in the title field are taken into account but not the modifications in the DateTimePickerView component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally resolved this problem making some controls when using the moment.js library.
Everything was working fine with the binding process of the custom datetimepickerview.

Here is a working jsfiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/29/)

The relevant code is here :

```
window.App.DateTimePickerView = Ember.View.extend(
  templateName: 'datetimepicker'
  didInsertElement: ->
    #this test is important and was the problem
    if @.get 'value' 
      @$('input').val moment.utc(@.get 'value').format('LLL')
    onChangeDate = (ev) =>
      date = moment.utc(ev.date).format('LLL')
      @.set "value", date
    @$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(format: 'dd/MM/yyyy', pickTime: false).on "changeDate", onChangeDate
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem lies in the fact that you where trying to listen on an event fired from the **datetimepicker** which is not captured, and thus the model value not set.

To make things more solid you should get the **datetimepicker** current date value in your `doneEditing` function, just before saving the model back to the store.

Let me show in code what I mean:

```
window.App.EventController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
  ...

  doneEditing: ->
    // relevant code line
    @get("model").set("date_begin", $('.datetimepicker').data('date'))
    @set "isEditing", false
    @get("store").commit()
  ...
)
```

And here your (working) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/3QR6n/).

Hope it helps

**Edit**

After reading your comment I've modified the input field inside your **datetimepicker** template. Please see [here an updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AmP4A/1/) that also initializes the input field of the **datetimepicker** on edit begin when calling `edit`.

```
...
edit: ->
  @set "isEditing", true
  startDate = @get("model").get("date_begin")
  @$(".datetimepicker").data({date: startDate}).datetimepicker("update")
...
```

You are now safe to remove the `onDateChange` function and do init and save inside your `edit` and `doneEditing` respectively, applying format or whatever.

**Edit 2**

Reading your last comment, this is how you register `customEvents` for example in your `App.DateTimePickerView`:

```
  ...
  customEvents: {
    changedate: "changeDate"
  }
  ...
```

this way Ember will be aware of your custom events. You can register whatever events you want but notice that the keyname is lowercased and the value must have the event name to listen to camelcased. For more infos on custom events see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events).

Please see here for another [update jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/AmP4A/2/) with the `changeDate` custom event registered.

Comment: Alright this is perfect and works very well. One last question : is there a way to use the onChangeDate function in order to update the model when a date is picked : I mean call an updateDate function of the EventController that will do the `@get("model").set("date_begin", $('.datetimepicker').data('date'))` and then use the doneEditing to perform only the commit ?

Comment: Yes I see, but I do not know if I well understand the concept of custom events or if it is relevant in that case. But I just saw something interesting : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmP4A/3/) here I started from your second jsfiddle and I removed the part using momentjs in the onChangeDate function : the binding is working perfectly. Indeed there were an error saying moment is not defined thus the binding was not performed. Now we can see that the values are well updated everywhere the model is displayed. Now I cannot understand why moment is not defined whereas I imported it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: well, I guess if it's solves your problem than it's relevant :)

Comment: ember is already listening to a bunch of events, but of course not all events that might be fired, so if you need to listen and act on an event that is not already registered from ember you have to register it yourself to make ember aware of this event, makes sense?

Comment: Yes I understand. Sorry I did not complete my comment. I did an update to explain that the binding is working great removing the call to momentjs in the onChangeDate because of an error saying that moment was not defined.

Comment: oh yes I see, the problem with `moment` is strange, but it might be related to jsfiddle or something, have you setup the same example also locally or on another site like jsbin? just to sure it's a script loading problem...

Comment: Hum, on my application momentjs is working great and correctly formats the date in the fields but not in the attribute of the model (date_begin is not sent with the put request). If I remove the call to moment in the onChangeDate, the attribute is well updated and appears in the put request. So from the beginning, the real problem is with momentjs... very strange.